# Dictionary form to ask if someone wants something

Tags: grammar

I can't find much about it but I found an example to illustrate it:

> 温めますか
>
> Do you want it heated? [weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B%22/2)

I don't understand how the dictionary form can have the meaning 'to want' and what is the difference with てもらいたいですか, てほしいですか, etc.

Comment: I’ve seen people saying 食べる when “offering food” to a friend, I guess it’s more like “will you eat?”, it should be one of the cases where it’s just a thing from Japanese language where there’s not counterpart in English

Comment: 温めますか just means like "Do I heat it up?", there is nothing special about it and I think it's different from asking someone something like "食べる?" for "will you eat it/do you want to eat it"

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I know,

Instead  of saying "want" (ーたい), it's more polite to say "shall I" (ーましょうか).

If you want to ask someone if they want something heated, it would be polite to say this:

温めましょうか?

Comment: Apparently 温めますか is often said in the konbini so your answer doesn't seem to work.